# NextGEN Gallery not working with Custom Post Type UI

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I am working on a project for a client that features products that they sell using Custom Posts Types. I am looking to have an image rotator to feature rotating images of the products on each specific product page.

I have always used the NextGEN gallery plugin but discovered that it does not seem to work with Custom Posts.

I was wondering if anyone may have any suggestions or alternate plugins that they might recommend that would work with Custom Post Types.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried owl carousel?

Comment: no. need plugin